# Creating a stack in C, structure for nodes

Tags: c, struct, stack, typedef, nodes

I have been given a structure for the nodes that will make up my stack but I am having trouble understanding it.

```
    struct stackNode 
{
  char data;
  struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct stackNode StackNode; 
typedef StackNode *StackNodePtr;
```

I understand that I have a  structure called stackNode, renamed StackNode (or a second type with the same everything except name?), which has two types, a char and a pointer to a stackNode.

I am not sure what the final line means, can anyone step through and explain it to me? I *think* it means there is a new type, which is a pointer to a StackNode, called a StackNodePtr. Is this right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, whenever you use a `StackNodePtr` you are essentially using a `StackNode*` that is in turn equal to a `struct stackNode*`. The spacing and asterix placement can evidently lead to some confusion. I would *personally* write it as `typedef StackNode* StackNodePtr;` to be a bit clearer with what gets typedef-ed to what.

These three lines would be equal:

```
StackNodePtr myPointer;
StackNode *myPointer; 
struct stackNode *myPointer;
```

The reason for the `typedef struct stackNode StackNode` is usually to avoid having to write `struct` whenever using it.

Comment: Okay. I'm have some issues with the pop method I've written to go with this stack. I think I have it very wrong or something because I'm getting a number of errors.  I try to assign the header of the linked list to a temporary stackNode, and used this `temp.nextPtr = *topPtr->nextPtr;` with *topPtr being a StackNodePtr to the header. I get the error "request for member ‘nextPtr’ in something not a structure or union", do you know why? (Sorry formatting... I'm new)

Comment: If you have a StackNodePtr, you don't need the asterix. See the answer for an explanation (it is "included" in the StackNodePtr typedef)!

Comment: Oh, yeah, I have tried it without the asterix and I get a different error message. With `temp.nextPtr = topPtr->nextPtr;` This time I get "request for member ‘nextPtr’ in something not a structure or union."

Comment: Is temp a StackNode and topPtr a StackNodePtr?

Comment: If I make them both StackNodePtr (and adjust . to -> accordingly), I get the error "request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union".

In the question give to me that I am solving, topPtr must me a StackNodePtr.

Comment: I would suggest making a small, self-contained example and post a new question with both the code and all the error messages!

Comment: If this question is answered, please consider accepting the answer for future reference. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You have three things.

1. You are declaring a type named `struct stackNode`, and providing the structure definition.
2. You are defining a new type, `StackNode`, that is an alias of (and is type-compatible with) `struct stackNode`.
3. You are defining a new type, `StackNodePtr`, that is an alias of (and, again, type-compatible with,) `StackNode *` (and `struct stackNode *`).

The poing being, that instead of declaring your node variable as `struct stackNode newNode`, and your list head as `struct stackNode *head`, you declare your node variable as `StackNode newNode` and your list head as `StackNodePtr head`.

This is a fairly common idiom, although some people recommend against doing it this way. (And, of course, other people insist that this is the right way, too.)